# MongoDB - filtering an array based on another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I'm using MongoDB and this is what my documents look like

```
{
    "_id": 1,
   "arr1": ["a", "a", "b", "c"],
   "arr2": [1, 4, 2, 3 ],
},
{
    "_id": 2,
   "arr1": ["z", "a", "b", "a"],
   "arr2": [1, 4, 2, 3 ],
}
```

The arrays in keys `arr1` and `arr2` always have the same length. I would like to aggregate the data such that can I filter out the values in `arr2` based on `arr1`.

For example, if I filter my collection based on `arr1` looking for `a`, I would like to get something like that:

```
{ "_id": 1, "arr1": "a", "arr2": 1},
{ "_id": 1, "arr1": "a", "arr2": 4 },
{ "_id": 2, "arr1": "a", "arr2": 3 },
{ "_id": 2, "arr1": "a", "arr2": 3 }
```

Is there some method to accomplish that using MongoDB?

Thanks,

Uirá

Comment: check answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
db.col1.aggregate([
   {  $unwind: 
         { path:"$arr2", includeArrayIndex: "i"}},
   {  $project: 
         {
           "arr2":1,
           "arr1": { $slice: ["$arr1","$i",1] }}
          },
   {$unwind: "$arr1"}
   {$match: { "arr1":"a" }}
 ])
```

**Output from first $unwind Stage**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a", "a", "b", "c" ], "arr2" : 1, "i" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a", "a", "b", "c" ], "arr2" : 4, "i" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a", "a", "b", "c" ], "arr2" : 2, "i" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a", "a", "b", "c" ], "arr2" : 3, "i" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "z", "a", "b", "a" ], "arr2" : 1, "i" : NumberLong(0) }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "z", "a", "b", "a" ], "arr2" : 4, "i" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "z", "a", "b", "a" ], "arr2" : 2, "i" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "z", "a", "b", "a" ], "arr2" : 3, "i" : NumberLong(3) }
```

**Out put after second project stage**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "b" ], "arr2" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "c" ], "arr2" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "z" ], "arr2" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "b" ], "arr2" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 3 }
```

**second $unwind Output**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : "a", "arr2" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : "a", "arr2" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : "b", "arr2" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : "c", "arr2" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : "z", "arr2" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : "a", "arr2" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : "b", "arr2" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : "a", "arr2" : 3 }
```

**Final $match output:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr1" : [ "a" ], "arr2" : 3 }
```

Comment: Nice, it worked flawlessly. I also liked the way you've explained this query, showing the output of each step. Very instructive. Thank you.

Comment: glad to hear that. You are welcome. Thanks for accepting answer.